# Remove duplicate tuples in an RDD in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD as list of pairs of tuples:-

```
[((1.1, 1.2), (0.1, 0.1)),
 ((1.1, 1.2), (0.4, 2.1)),
 ((0.1, 0.1), (1.1, 1.2)),
 ((9.0, 9.0), (9.1, 9.1)),
 ((0.4, 2.1), (1.1, 1.2)),
 ((9.1, 9.1), (9.0, 9.0))]
```

How can I remove the duplicate tuples from this RDD and get the required output as:

```
[((1.1, 1.2), (0.1, 0.1)),
 ((1.1, 1.2), (0.4, 2.1)),
 ((9.1, 9.1), (9.0, 9.0))]
```

I have already tried distinct() but not getting the required output.

Comment: I don't see any attempt or explanation of why it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: It seems like you want to remove consider `(x, y)` and `(y, x)` as duplicates of each other. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to get the distinct pairs of tuples, disregarding the order in which they appear. Your attempt, `rdd.distinct()` does not work in this case because it only removes duplicate rows (order matters).

One thing you can do is to sort your rows so that pairs of elements will always appear in the same order, and then call `distinct()`:

```python
rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).distinct().collect()
```

On your data, this produces:

```python
[((9.0, 9.0), (9.1, 9.1)),
 ((0.1, 0.1), (1.1, 1.2)),
 ((0.4, 2.1), (1.1, 1.2))]
```